# Play framework error while creating a SOAP service using (play version 2.5.4 + Java )

Tags: soap, playframework-2.0, soap-client

I am new to play framework. I need to create a soap service in play framework using java. I followed [this](http://www.imind.eu/web/2013/11/07/developing-soap-services-using-play-framework-2-2-x/) article but was not able to run the application - `activator/play version - 2.5.4`

While accessing the service I got this error.

```
[warn] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController#0' defined in class path resource [cxf.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController$]: Factory method 'getInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController$.play$api$mvc$Results$_setter_$TooManyRequests_$eq(Lplay/api/mvc/Results$Status;)V
[error] application - 

! @714g94j1n - Internal server error, for (GET) [/service/hello] ->

play.api.PlayException: Cannot init the Global object[Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController#0' defined in class path resource [cxf.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController$]: Factory method 'getInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController$.play$api$mvc$Results$_setter_$TooManyRequests_$eq(Lplay/api/mvc/Results$Status;)V]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$.apply(GlobalSettings.scala:229)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:99)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.applicationModule(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:99)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
```

My codes:

```
Build.sbt:

name := "play-cxf-hello"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.3.2.RELEASE"
libraryDependencies += "eu.imind.play" %% "play-cxf_play24" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-bindings-soap" % "3.1.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws" % "3.1.7"

plugins.sbt:
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

applicationContext.xml:
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
 ">

    <!-- Import Apache CXF configuration and Play! transport plugin. -->
    <import resource="classpath:cxf.xml"/>

    <!-- Define Hello World endpoint. It will be available at http://localhost:9000/service/hello -->
    <jaxws:endpoint name="helloWorld"
                    transportId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
                    address="/service/hello"
                    implementor="services.hello.HelloWorldImpl"/>

</beans>

Global.java:

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    protected ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        ctx.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application app) {
        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```

Can anybody advice me on this?

Comment: did you solve this problem? having a similar problem. It seems to come from the ClassPath object where you initialize it in the global class, where you pass the applicationContext.xml file